# Ubuntu 18.04 Mate. Problem with switching keyboard layout

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, mate

I use Ubuntu 18.04 Mate Edition with installed Unity. I've got several keyboard layouts and they're switching nice in Mate, but when I try to do it in Unity (upd: by shortcut) nothing happens.
I've configure both Mate and Unity settings.

[Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXvhZ.png)
[Mate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ8y0.png)

```
ptrknvk@stiven:~$ cat /etc/default/keyboard
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"

ptrknvk@stiven:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
@as []
```

Comment: Mate screenshot can't for some reason show the all list, but it's the same "Super+Space" shortcut.

Comment: Does it work in Unity if you click the input source indicator in the top bar and change layout that way?

Comment: Yes, but I rather use hotkeys.

Comment: Ok, then it's really a shortcut problem, right? Please edit your question and let us know what these two commands output: 1. `cat /etc/default/keyboard` 2. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: Edited. See a post.

Comment: Nothing there which would explain it. Then I would try to set the shortcuts for layout switching again. The shortcut for next source seems to be the default one, while the shortcut for previous source is currently something else.